# Adding Mobile to Sinch Conference Call

Tags: android, sinch, android-sinch-api

I'm using [Sinch API](https://www.sinch.com/) for implementing Conference Call in my Android App. I need to create Conference Room, then add one SinchClient and one mobile/landline to that conference.

I searched a lot and some answered to use [ConferenceCallout restapi](https://www.sinch.com/docs/voice/rest/#Callouts), but I need to do it in **pure** android. What is a good way to implement it?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: you need to check [this](https://www.sinch.com/docs/voice/android/#setupaconferencecall)

Comment: It is just to create a conference room, my problem is about adding client and mobile to call.

Comment: and my Problem is how to Conference Call like a Single call, i found some code but in this app is sharing a link to join conference call thats is my problem

Comment: @ShakeelAhmed Actually its been quite a while. I don't do Android anymore, but I'm sure if you follow the documentation carefully, you'll make it.  Good luck

Answer (score 1):

to add a participant to the call you need to do a rest call, the rest client is not part of the android SDK since you usually dont have the secret in the app. I would connect the user to the conference in the ICE event and then make a conferenceCAllout at the same time in that rest event

https://www.sinch.com/docs/voice/rest#ICE

https://www.sinch.com/docs/voice/rest#Callouts

We support both signed request and basic auth

Comment: Well I need to configure a Callback url in my dashboard. I searched a lot but I couldn't find where to do it. I tried in my Dashboard under DevTools -> API Explorer, but it wasn't like what I read in docs and tutorials . And if there were any example doing the way you said, would help me a lot. Thanks

Comment: I could make the callback url but when I try to request I receive following error "errorCode": 40102,
  "message": "Invalid Signature.",
  "reference": "A:85361d4f-859d-4689-9aa8-eb05d298c406_WopyFY3IWU6kx0HSbA26GA"               I tried to make the request with header which is provided in my sinch Dashboard, but it seems they are not correct in that case. Please let me know how to do it. Thanks

Comment: When using signautre you need to create it every time, you cant copy it from the dashboard. Either you need to implement code or use basic auth

Comment: there is callback tutorials here https://www.sinch.com/tutorials/getting-second-number-testing-sinch-callbackswebhooks-ngrok/